# How to get 2 div elements in a list element to use available width on page?

Tags: html, css, width, html-lists

I want my 'settings' div to use the available width on a page. Sometimes that is 1000px, sometimes that is 780px, sometimes it's 600px.
I tried setting the width to 100%, but that results in the div being put on the next line, instead of what I desire: next to the 'title' div.
So in the example below, the div with 'Gender' is always 180px wide, but the setting div (with value 'Male') should then take the available width on the page.

How can I do it?

```
<style>
.profilesettings {
    padding-left:0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.profilesettings > li {
    width:100%;
}

.profilesettings li.header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #888;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#901C51;
}

.profilesettings div.title {
width:180px;
    float:left;
}

.profilesettings div.title h3 {
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
}

.profilesettings div.setting {
width:780px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
</style>


<ul class="profilesettings">
    <li class="header"><h2>Details</h2></li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Gender</div>
        <div class="setting">
            Male
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/CLzjt/)

Firstly, make sure `ul` has a width of 100%, then remove the float and width from `.profilesettings div.setting` and simply give it `overflow:hidden;`

```
html,body, ul{
    width:100%; /* <--- ensure the list is the max width of the page */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.profilesettings {
    padding-left:0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.profilesettings > li {
    width:100%;
}
.profilesettings li.header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #888;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#901C51;
}
.profilesettings div.title {
    width:180px;
    float:left;
}
.profilesettings div.title h3 {
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
}
.profilesettings div.setting {
    overflow:hidden; /* <-- remove float and width and add overflow to force div to take up remaining space */
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
```